# vuforia and Unity3d new ui system

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to use unity 3d UI system to show content when ImageTarget is recognized but there a problem which I couldn't handle . UI contents ( Buttons, Text ,...) are always appear on the screen even when imagetarget is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't deactivate all the objects in the UI and then re-activate again when your image is recognized, just like vuforia does to load GameObjects?

srry I'm not able to create comments

Comment: I don't have the vuforia example because I'm at my job, but try this...
create a variable like
`public GameObject[] myUIComponents;`
you should put all the objects that you want to activate inside the array(all objects should be deactivated from the editor)
Vuforia has a method that is used to activate all the objects when the Image target is recognized, so... inside this method you can create a loop:
`foreach(GameObject go in myUIComponents){ go.setActive(true);}`